# Consulta MySQLi retorna FALSE ao invés de retornar registros do banco

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, query, mysqli

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma consulta dos dados de login do usuário no banco com php porém notei que a variável que recebe a função que faz a consulta sempre retorna vazia e fiz um var_dump dessa variável que me mostrou apenas o valor FALSE(O que indica que houve um erro na consulta, certo?). Abaixo o código para melhor entendimento.

**Erro:**

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/dao/usuario_dao.php on line 35
>   NULL

**'valida_login.php' é chamada pelo form de login e recebe os dados do usuário via 'POST'.**

```
<?php

session_start();

//Recebe os campos da página login
$input_usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$input_senha = $_POST['senha'];

include ('../dao/usuario_dao.php');

$usuario = seleciona_usuario($input_usuario, $input_senha);

//Se o resultado retornar vazio executa
if(empty($usuario))
{
    //Mensagem de erro
    $_SESSION['login_erro'] = "Usuário e/ou senha inválido(s)! Por favor, tente novamente.";


    var_dump($usuario);
    //Redireciona para a tela de login
    //header('Location: ../index.php');
}
else
{
    //Sessions que recebem os valores dos campos do banco de dados
    $_SESSION['nome_usuario'] = $usuario['nome'];
    $_SESSION['acesso_usuario'] = $usuario['permissao'];
    $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $usuario['login'];

    $_SESSION['permissao'];

    if($_SESSION['acesso_usuario'] == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['permissao'] = "Master";
        header('Location: menu_master.php');
    }
    else//Implementar outras permissões
    {
        $_SESSION['permissao'] = "Usuário";
        header("Location: menu_usuario.php");
    }
}
```

**'usuario_dao.php' é onde está a função que faz a consulta no banco.**

```
<?php    
include ('../models/conexao.php');

//Função que seleciona usuário
function seleciona_usuario($login, $senha)
{
    $conn = conectar();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE (login='$login' AND senha=MD5('$senha'))";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Agradeço desde já à quem puder ajudar.

Comment: no arquivo usuario_dao.php adicione abaixo `$result = ...` o código a seguir `if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysqli_error());
}` e posta pra gente ver a causa

Comment: Ok, coloquei o código e aparentemente o próprio gerou um erro que diz que a função 'mysqli_error()' espera receber um parâmetro.



_**Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/centraljogos/dao/usuario_dao.php on line 35**_

Comment: eita, mas que coisa ! então coloca `$result` dentro da função `mysqli_error` e põe rodar pra ver

Comment: Agradeço pela retorno novamente. Pesquisando vi que a função esperava receber a conexão como parâmetro e consegui imprimir o erro que dá até vergonha de falar. hahaha Eu conseguia executar a query no PhpMyAdmin e no código não simplismente por que eu estava conectado com um banco diferente e o erro me retornou que a tabela que eu tentava acessar no código não existia. Peço desculpas por qualquer transtorno e agradeço à todos que ajudaram. Fazer o que? Vivendo e aprendendo. Obrigado.